# Difference between website and web application in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

What is the difference between a web site and a web application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net: Website or web application project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344473/asp-net-website-or-web-application-project)

Comment: another possible duplicate with a lot of answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application

Answer (score 6):

**FROM MCTS SELF-PACED TRAINING KIT**

Web applications and websites function and perform similarly, but web
applications differ from websites in several important ways. For example, with a **web application**:

■ You can create an MVC application.

■ Visual Studio stores the list of files in a project file (.csproj or .vbproj), rather than
relying on the folder structure.

■ You cannot mix Visual Basic and C#.

■ You cannot edit code without stopping a debugging session.

■ You can establish dependencies between multiple web projects.

■ You must compile the application before deployment, which prevents you from testing
a page if another page will not compile.

■ You do not have to store the source code on the server.

■ You can control the assembly name and version.

■ You cannot edit individual files after deployment without recompiling.

Comment: `You do not have to store the source code on the server.` why, with web sites, do you? I ask while I don't know shit about what kind of web **sites** can you make with MSVS: if you could tell me what language does it output on (or something) when doing a website project in it I might get a bigger picture, would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**WEB APPLICATION**

- You explicitly compile the source code on the computer that is used
  for development or source control.
- By default, compilation of code    files (excluding .aspx and .ascx
  files) produces a single assembly.
- Explicit namespaces are added to pages, controls, and classes by
  default.

**WEB SITE PROJECT**

- The source code is typically compiled dynamically (automatically) by
  ASP.NET on the server the first time a request is received after the
  site has been installed or updated.
- You can precompile the site (compile in advance on a development
  computer or on the server). By default, compilation produces multiple
  assemblies.
- Explicit namespaces are not added to pages, controls, and classes by
  default, but you can add them manually.