# What is the difference between web application and web site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to know what is the difference between web application and web site exactly?
Because I feel in trouble, as I want to integrate tasks. Part of them are built as a web site, and the other as a web application. When I added them to the web site and build the solution, I had many errors that I could not handle. It can't handle name spaces and some classes can't be read. Please help.

Comment: you could fix your question title to make it more easier that you want to know main differences between two website project types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698362/difference-between-website-and-web-application-in-visual-studio/11607329#11607329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web application is generally an application where the interface is delivered to you over the network/Internet. So a web application can reside on a website.

In the context of Visual studio, here is Microsoft's explanation of the differenve between the web application and web site projects: [link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880(VS.80).aspx#wapp_topic5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5)

Answer (score 3):

About your problem, perhaps you should add References to your project, so classes could be found?

Click on those not found classes and press Shift Alt F10 to find referenced classes in other project.

To answer the difference between web application and web site, you can see it [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1520-Difference-between-web-site-web-application.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can find a summary of differences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

I hope this helps.