# Do I need to select web Site or Web project?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, graph, amcharts

I am completely new to .net framework. I have to build a website that contain real time updating  graphs.

data takes directly through MS SQL database via web service. (Website contain graphs only which should update time time)

I noticed that VS 2015 has 2 options. **web site** and **web** **Application**.

Which one should I use for my project. Please guild me to select best option.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://goo.gl/rtYKPJ

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698362/difference-between-website-and-web-application-in-visual-studio

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'Web Site' and 'Project' in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web Site or ASP.NET Web Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application)

Comment: Should I select Web site , Web form Application or web application ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO Web Application all the way. And use the publish wizard to deploy.

Web sites do not have a project file: everything in the project folder (and subfolders) is part of the project. This seems nice and easy until you want to be able to include/exclude things. It also assumes all the compilation is done on the web server (on the first load of each page). In practice in the medium to long term leads to work-arounds that would be unnecessary in a web application.

Comment: Should I select Web site , Web form Application or web application ?

Comment: @Joe you would be better going through a few tutorials: the development models are rather different between Web Forms, Web Pages or MVC. The former two can be done in a Web SIte project, all three in a Web Application: ie. there are five options.

Answer (score 0):

`web Application`. Click on *start Page -> New Project -> ASP.NET Web Application*

Click on *File -> New Project -> ASP.NET Web Application*

[image]

Comment: Should I select Web site , Web form Application or web application ?